# Making a dictionary from input in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a dictionary by getting the item name and the number of items from the user and make them a key,value pair. This is the code I have so far:

```
groceries={}
item,number=input("Enter item and number").split()
```

I am trying to make my code as short as possible and do not want to use the for loop. Is there a way to do this by adding one more line to my code? Meaning when I use `print(groceries)` I want to actually see the dictionary items that I entered.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can pass item as key in your `groceries dict` and pass value as number

```
item,number=input("Enter item and number ").split(' ')

groceries = {}
groceries[item] = number
```

Comment: What king of input to you expect ? Because using split and unpack in 2 elements, means the input if a 2-word string, then you zip them, so `for bar` makes `{f:b, o:a, r:r}` strange

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3.8 then you can make it even shorter with the walrus operator:

```py
print({(values := input("Enter item and number").split())[0]: values[1]})
```

If you want to update your existing dictionary:

```py
groceries = {"foo": "bar"}

print({**groceries, **{(values := input("Enter item and number").split())[0]: values[1]}})
```

Comment: That use of the walrus operator, makes the code so unreadable^^ readability should be in the top priorities

Comment: I agree but he said "I am trying to make my code as short as possible".